# Format names to title case

Tags: java, homework, functional-programming

So I'm writing a program to format names to title case and display them in alphabetic order.  Any advice please?  And how can i add more methods?

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{    
    //local variables
    string name1;
    string name2;

     myLib = new Library();

     /********************   Start main method  *****************/

     //prompt user for first Name
     System.out.print("Enter First Name : ");
     name1 = Keyboard.readChar(); 

     //prompt user for second
     System.out.print("Enter Second Name : ");
     name2 = Keyboard.readChar(); 

     //Format names to Title Case
     name1.replace(0, name1.length(), name1.toString().toLowerCase());
     name2.replace(0, name2.length(), name2.toString().toLowerCase()); 

     name1.setCharAt(0, Character.toTitleCase(name1.charAt(0)));
     name2.setCharAt(0, Character.toTitleCase(name2.charAt(0)));

     //clear the screen
     myLib.clrscr();

     //Display names in alphabet order
     if (name1.toString().compareTo(name2.toString()) >= 0) {
         System.out.println(name2 + " " + name1);    
     } else {
         System.out.println(name1 + " " + name2);
     }    

     //pause the screen
     //myLib.pause();

  } //end main method

} //end
```

Comment: Could you post the `string` class too?

Comment: @palacsint First rename, then post. Calling a class `string` is confusing itself and using a lowercase class name is too strange in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Create a List

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String();
```

and add (you can also use something like `while(! stringRead.isEmpty()) {..}` )

```
name = Keyboard.readChar()).toLowerCase();
al.add(name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1));
```

*EDIT after comment*

1°) then Sort (the list is 'cloned') and print directly frome the Constructor `return`
 This solution is recommended to protect data published in a Web page.

```
System.out.println(new TreeSet<String>(al).toString());
```

2°) The List is sorted then printed

```
Collections.sort(al);
System.out.println(al.toString());
```

Comment: References to objects should be as generic as possible (i.e. `List<String> a1` is preferred over `ArrayList<String> a1`)

Comment: @lchau . Exact, thanks - A mistake I maid sometime : because Eclipse's completion is too useful, I forgot to refer to Interface by removing `Array`

Comment: +1 and a note: `Collections.sort` would keep the duplicated elements in the list (unlike the `TreeSet` and other sets).

Answer (score 1):

Usually in these cases you can implement a `Comparator<String>`. This way it'll be portable, and can make use of the [Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) (e.g. `Collections.sort(collection, TITLE_CASE_COMPARATOR);`.

```
private static final Comparator<String> TITLE_CASE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<String>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) { 
     // null-safe checks
     // equal
     if (o1 == null && o2 == null) { return 0; }
     // greater than, implies o2 is null
     else if (o1 != null) { return 1; } 
     // less than, implies o1 is null
     else if (o2 != null) { return -1; } 

     // title case comparison here
   }
};
```

Some other ideas/methods you can also consider:

- Check cases where title cases do not apply (just to name a few [there are more]: a, an, the, or)
- Think about [choosing the right collection](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65), some collections take a `Comparator` as an argument which maintains the order for you (depending when/where you want to display the sorted results)
- You might also consider a pretty formatting for it, such as the total of entries that were processed (maintaining a history of previous inputs)
- Additional considerations for handling input (empty input, ignoring invalid characters, duplicate entries)